# C++: multimap is showing unintended output

Tags: c++, stl

multimap is showing unintended output. My intended output is

```
a
b,c
d
```

but it is showing

```
a
c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,
d
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   multimap<char,vector<char> > mmap; //multimap 

   mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('a',vector<char>('b','c'))); //insert to multimap
   mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('d',vector<char>()));

   vector<char>::iterator veciter; 
   multimap<char,vector<char> >::iterator mapiter;

   for ( mapiter = mmap.begin(); mapiter != mmap.end(); ++mapiter) 
   {
      cout << mapiter->first << endl;

      for (veciter = mapiter->second.begin(); veciter != mapiter->second.end(); ++veciter)
      {
          cout << *veciter << ',';
      }
      cout<<endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'b' has the ordinal value 98.  Are you getting 98 'c' characters? :).  Might need {} (an initializer list if you can use C++11 features).

Comment: @DavidO I got warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x when I changed to curly braces and still getting same output.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a C++11 feature (or C++0x), you have to enable g++ to allow it by setting one of the flags mentioned.  Otherwise, since it's just two elements, push_back().  Or if it's a lot of elements, initialize an array, and use the array pointer version of the vector constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor `vector<char>('b','c')`, creates a vector which holds 98 values of 'a', as the integer value for 'b' is 98, and you are calling the constructor [`explicit vector( size_t size, const _Tp& initial ) ...`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/). To correct your code you can use an [intializer list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/), if you support C++ standard. The code would look like: `mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('a',vector<char>{'b','c'}));`

Comment: @Vito Corleone: That's because you're not using the `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` flag (either will do) on your compiler's command line.  The initializer list is a C++11 standard feature.  You're running in C++03 mode.  If you can't turn on the flag, then you'll probably have to push_back a couple of elements, or use an array to initialize with.

Comment: @Rondogiannis Aristophanes I got warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x when I changed to curly braces and still getting same output

Comment: @DavidO How can i turn on C++11 standard feature flag?

Comment: The first time *I* saw that message, I read the error message, and when I was still unclear, I looked it up in the GCC online manual.  Your version of g++ probably doesn't fully support -std=c++11, but the error message is telling you that it does support -std=c++0x (which should be good enough in this case).  If I were compiling "mytest.cpp", I might type `g++ -std=c++0x -o mytest mytest.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can see what element store in mmap memory space.

mmap.insert (pair >('a',vector('b','c'))) ,creates a vector has 98 values of 'a'

you can use like this:

```
mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('a',vector<char>())); 

mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('b',vector<char>())); 

mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('c',vector<char>())); 

mmap.insert (pair<char,vector<char> >('d',vector<char>()));
```

hope to help you.